# Removing borders around webpage

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In this template by Colorlib: https://colorlib.com/demo?theme=pemodule
I'm trying to remove the purple borders around the outside of the website. I can't seem to figure out in the CSS how this border is achieved and how I can remove it.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: isn't that just a body background ??

Comment: Are you talking about the CSS rule `background: #4b379a;` that is on the `<body>` element of the iframe?

Comment: @mhatch Yes, RyanDay has resolved it for me. It was a the background of the body, which was given a margin I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is the background of the `body` and the rest of the website has a margin which creates the space between it and the edges of the viewport.

**in main.css, line 1927:**

```
body {
    background: #4b379a;
}
```

**in main.css, line 1931:**

```
.main-wrapper-first {
    width: 68.75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the body tag has the following:

```
body {
background: #4b379a;
}
```

change that to:

```
body {
background: white;
}
```

Comment: (S)he want's to get rid of the border, not set it white.

Comment: Are you finding that in the frame.css file? Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Set these things in your CSS (I don't know if you need the `!important`s), but here:

```
.main-wrapper, .main-wrapper-first {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important; 
}
```

If you are adding this to the CSS, place this at the bottom.